# Android App crashes when disabling the location permission from settings?

Tags: android, permissions, xamarin.android, location, runtime-permissions

I am working on Xamarin Android Application. I have asked a location permission from my app which if I enable from the app works properly.
But when i put the app in background and go to settings and disable the location permission and start the app again, the app crashes. What could be the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: try catch in your code?

Comment: `What could be the possible solution to this problem?` that depends on the reason of the crash. Show the crash logs.

Comment: Vlad, As soon as I revoke the location permission from settings the app gets restarted, so I cannot view the log.

Answer (score 0):

From Android M Android Required some permission at Run time like Location permission. when you disable that permission from settings then when app running on background it not found that permission to access GPS in background.That's why app crash. to avoid app crash show some message when permission declined and Handle Exception using try catch block.

Read more about android Run time permission from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Vinay, I have an activity with two fragments, where do i show the message? I have implemented checkselfpermission in onResume of the activity to show a toast on whether permission is granted or not

Comment: check your Log where app crash when disable location permission and add try-catch block to handle exception.

Comment: Vinay, As soon as I revoke the location permission from settings the app gets restarted, so I cannot view the log